# List of escape sequences for Postgresql string data types

Tags: postgresql, string, postgresql-9.5

I'm trying to find the documentation of a complete list of escape sequences for string data types in Postgresql.  So for example, if you need to escape a quote character inside of a quoted string, you would use `\"`.  Different DBMSs use different jargon, so I'm having a hard time finding what to search for.

I found this, but it doesn't look exhaustive to me.  In this link, search for "The following special backslash sequences are recognized by COPY FROM".

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-copy.html

## EDIT:

I knew it wasn't exhaustive.  See the `\\` character here:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html

Then look at "4.1.2.2. String Constants with C-style Escapes" in this link.  Also read what's written in CAUTION.  This is making me humble, and I hope it is for others.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html

Comment: "*if you need to escape a quote character inside of a quoted string, you would use \"* - no that's wrong. A `"` does not need to be "escaped" in a SQL string literal. The only character that needs escaping in SQL is the single quote itself and that is escaped by doubling it. `'Arthur''s House'`. But the escape sequences for CSV input files used by the `copy` command have nothing to do with the syntax for SQL string literals.

Comment: I'm looking for others as well... \n, \t, new line characters in data, etc...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Is that for text files to be imported using `copy` or for SQL literals?

Comment: well, some imports for us are done via copy command (our automated ones), and some are done via phpMyAdmin site (yes for postgresql) using the import option

Comment: You can also use the dollar-quote in situations you need to escape a lot of quotes. Example:

SELECT $str$'la'lla' test ''$str$

Comment: Not sure what you are asking about here either. I don't think I've ever had a problem with <tab>, <enter> or anything else, especially when using copy. With that said, if you are using phpMyAdmin, there may be some things that aren't available to you. I know SQuireL, for example, doesn't allow $$ (even in functions) among other items, so I'd try whatever you are trying with psql or PgAdmin.

Comment: I, too, think you are distracted by the wrong question. Consider: [Insert varchar with single quotes in PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12320729/939860)