# Postgresql, commas in string_agg function

Tags: postgresql, syntax

**Need**

FIELD like this, with `'` and without `,` at the end of whole field.

```
{name:'color',value:'red'},{name:'width',value:'300 ml'}
```

**Tried**

```
string_agg(distinct '{name:\'' || param_name || '\',value:\'' || value || '\'},','') as "FIELD"
```

but error behind 2nd `\`

```
SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"
```

With `,` at the end of whole field, I don't know how to do that.

Thanks.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320729/470530).

Comment: In case you are trying to generate a JSON value: are you aware that the value you are generating is invalid JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to escape a ' in a string in postgres, you have to double it

[List of escape sequences for Postgresql string data types](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/123746/list-of-escape-sequences-for-postgresql-string-data-types)

so this give you this :

```
select string_agg(distinct '{name:''' || name || ''',value:''' || value || '''}',',') as "FIELD"
```

I tested it, it works =)

However, i don't know why you want to create this field, but it's probably better to follow a_horse_with_no_name's answer and use Jsonb_agg and look around Json manipulation in Postgres

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

Comment: It works, thanks. :) And what about comma at the end of whole field?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to generate JSON, it is easier to use JSON functions for that, e.g.:

```
string_agg(distinct jsonb_build_object('name', param_name, 'value', value)::text, ',')
```

Or create a proper JSON array of the result:

```
jsonb_agg(distinct jsonb_build_object('name', param_name, 'value', value))
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/EPOX97933

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_names Hi, I think better solution is to have it in simply one sql command.

Comment: @genderbee: that is one SQL command - just two alternatives